# How to analyse only new added lines of code?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to use SonarQube on my project. The project is quite a big and scanning whole files take much time. Is it possible to scan only changed files in the last commit, and provide report based only on changed lines of code?
I want to check if added or modified lines make the project quality worst and I don't care about old code.

For example, if person A created a file with 9 bugs and then commited changes - the report and quality gate should show 9 bugs. Then person B edited the same file adding few lines containing 2 additional bugs, then commited changes - the report should show the 2 last bugs and quality gate should be executed on the last changes (so should consider the last 2 bugs)

I was able to narrow scan to only changed files in the last commit- but report is generated based on whole files. I had an idea about cutting only changed lines of code, paste them to new file and run sonar scan on the file - but I'm almost sure the SonarQube needs the whole context of file.

Is it possible to somehow achieve my usecase ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it is impossible. I saw a lot of similar questions. These are answers to two of them:

[New Code analysis only](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/new-code-analysis-only/2916?u=agabrys):

> **G Ann Campbell:**
>
> Analysis will always include all code. Why? Why take the time to
>   analyze all of it when only a file or two has been changed? Because
>   any given change can have far-reaching effects. I’ll give you two
>   examples:
>
> I check in a change that deprecates a much-used method. Suddenly,
>   issues about the use of deprecated code should be raised all over the
>   project, but because I only analyzed that one file, no new issues were
>   raised.
>
> I modify a much-used method to return null in some cases. Suddenly all
>   the methods that dereference the returned value without first
>   null-checking it are at risk of NullPointerExceptions. But only the
>   one file that I changed was analyzed, so none of those “Possible NPE”
>   issues are raised. Worse, they won’t be raised until after each
>   individual file happens to be touched.
>
> And that’s why all files are included in each analysis.

[I want sonar analysis on newly checkin code](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/i-want-sonar-analysis-on-newly-checkin-code/9009?u=agabrys):

> **G Ann Campbell:**
>
> First, the SonarQube interface and default Quality Gate are designed to help you focus 
>   on the New Code Period. You can’t keep analysis from picking up those
>   old issues, but you can decide to only pay attention to issues raised
>   on newly-changed code. That means you would essentially ignore the
>   issues on the left side of the project homepage with a white
>   background and focus instead on the New Code values over the yellow
>   background on the right. We call this [Fixing the Leak](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/fixing-the-water-leak/), or
>   alternately Clean as You Code.
>
> Second, if you have a commercial edition, then branch and PR analysis
>   are available to you. With Short-Lived Branch (SLB) and PR analysis
>   still covers all files, but all that’s reported in the UI is what’s
>   changed in the PR / SLB.
>
> Ideally, you’ll combine both of these things to make sure your new
>   code stays clean.

The position in this matter has not changed over the last years, so don't expect it will be changed.