# Sonarqube analysis for selected modules

Tags: maven, sonarqube, static-analysis

I have a multimodules project with many dependencies. Until now after successful build I was performing sonar analysis of whole project. To save time and build project I detect which modules have been changed and run maven command:

```
mvn install -pl module1,module5,module2 -amd
```

Is there any way to do static analysis only for built modules? Something like mvn sonar:sonar -pl module1,module5,module2 -amd? of course it doesn't work, do you have any idea?

I know that there is option:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -pl !module2
```

but my project has more than 50 modules so if commit change only 5 modules I will have to list 45 others modules.

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube always requires full scan. If you exclude some modules and execute the scanner, then excluded modules will disappear from SonarQube. It means there is no such flag.

Read more: [How to analyse only new added lines of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56094245/4944847)

Comment: The thing is that per commit I use sonarqube in preview mode and sonarToGerrit pipeline plugin. So actually I don't publish any results to sonarqube instance. Full scan is performed in other part of flow.

Comment: One more time. Any flag of this kind does not exist because SonarScanner is expecting that everything is scanned. The flag for switching to preview mode (`sonar.analysis.mode`) was deprecated in 6.6, and removed in 7.7 (last information about it is in 7.6). If you want to scan only part of your modules, then you have two options. 1) generate `sonar-project.properties` on the fly with only interesting modules and use it instead of `sonar:sonar`. 2) execute `sonar:sonar` on modified `pom.xml` which does not include unchanged modules.